# Margin pushes element out of view when resizing

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Grid` wherein I have positioned a number of elements. One of them is a `Label` which is centered 30 pixels from the top of the grid.

When the user resizes the `Grid` the `Label` remains 30 pixels from the top which is what I want... until the height of the `Grid` becomes less than 30 + label height and the `Label` begins to disappear at the bottom of the grid.

I would like the `Label` to stay 30 pixels from the top **except** when there is not enough space for the margin and the `Label`, whereupon I want the margin to shrink and allow the `Label` to remain in view as long as possible.

I have tried various permutations of `RowDefinitions` without success. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this if it is not too much of a clutter for the layout:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Lorem Ipsum"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I added a third RowDefinition after experimentation which suits my needs even better. The margin shrinking happens on the top **and** bottom and looks smoother.